# What is the practical use of phantom references - JAVA?

Tags: java

Searched a lot about phantom reference but unable to find its practical usage. And logically the get() method returns null in case of Phantom References

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can follow this [blog](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references):

> What good are PhantomReferences? I'm only aware of two serious cases
>   for them: first, they allow you to determine exactly when an object
>   was removed from memory. They are in fact the only way to determine
>   that. This isn't generally that useful, but might come in handy in
>   certain very specific circumstances like manipulating large images: if
>   you know for sure that an image should be garbage collected, you can
>   wait until it actually is before attempting to load the next image,
>   and therefore make the dreaded OutOfMemoryError less likely.
>
> Second, PhantomReferences avoid a fundamental problem with
>   finalization: finalize() methods can "resurrect" objects by creating
>   new strong references to them. So what, you say? Well, the problem is
>   that an object which overrides finalize() must now be determined to be
>   garbage in at least two separate garbage collection cycles in order to
>   be collected. When the first cycle determines that it is garbage, it
>   becomes eligible for finalization. Because of the (slim, but
>   unfortunately real) possibility that the object was "resurrected"
>   during finalization, the garbage collector has to run again before the
>   object can actually be removed. And because finalization might not
>   have happened in a timely fashion, an arbitrary number of garbage
>   collection cycles might have happened while the object was waiting for
>   finalization. This can mean serious delays in actually cleaning up
>   garbage objects, and is why you can get OutOfMemoryErrors even when
>   most of the heap is garbage.

Also read: [The Mysterious Phantom Reference](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kcpeppe/archive/2011/09/29/mysterious-phantom-reference)

> Consider the following code.
>
> ```
> public class Foo {
>
>     private String bar;
>
>     public Foo(String bar) {
>         this.bar = bar;
>     }
>
>     public String foo() {
>         return bar;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> So lets say after the object has been completely dereferenced by the
>   application I want to some how call foo(). Here is some code that I
>   expected to work that would do this with one niggle.
>
> ```
> // initialize
> ReferenceQueue<Foo> queue = new ReferenceQueue<Foo>();
> ArrayList< PhantomReference<Foo>> list=new ArrayList<PhantomReference<Foo>>();
>
> for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
>     Foo o = new Foo( Integer.toOctalString( i));
>     list.add(new PhantomReference<Foo>(o, queue));
> }
>
> // make sure the garbage collector does it’s magic
> System.gc();
>
> // lets see what we’ve got
> Reference<? extends Foo> referenceFromQueue;
> for ( PhantomReference<Foo> reference : list)
>     System.out.println(reference.isEnqueued());
>
> while ( (referenceFromQueue = queue.poll()) != null) {
>     System.out.println(referenceFromQueue.get());
>     referenceFromQueue.clear();
> }
> ```
>
> PhantomReference takes an instance of Foo and a ReferenceQueue. Since
>   no handles are kept to Foo, it should immediately be dead. Next, tell
>   the VM to collect as there isn’t enough in heap for it to trigger a
>   collection naturally. The first thing I’m going to ask the
>   PhantomReference is; have you been enqueued. In this case the answer
>   will be true. Next I ask the queue for the reference but as you can
>   see, calling get() always returns null.   About the only solution that
>   made sense is to wrap the resources or objects you wanted to interact
>   with in a subclass of PhantomReference.
>
> ```
> public class FinalizeStuff<Foo> extends PhantomReference<Foo> {
>
>     public FinalizeStuff(Foo foo, ReferenceQueue<? super Foo> queue) {
>         super(foo, queue);
>     }
>
>     public void bar() {
>         System.out.println("foobar is finalizing resources");
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> In this case I’m not going to wrap Foo in the subclass as that would
>   seem to violate the spirit of PhantomReference. Instead I’m going to
>   wrap resources associated with Foo and interact with them. Now I can
>   do this.
>
> ```
> // initialize
> ReferenceQueue<Foo> queue = new ReferenceQueue<Foo>();
> ArrayList< FinalizeStuff<Foo>> list = new ArrayList<FinalizeStuff<Foo>>();
> ArrayList<Foo> foobar = new ArrayList<Foo>();
>
> for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
>     Foo o = new Foo( Integer.toOctalString( i));
>     foobar.add(o);
>     list.add(new FinalizeStuff<Foo>(o, queue));
> }
>
> // release all references to Foo and make sure the garbage collector does it’s magic
> foobar = null;
> System.gc();
>
> // should be enqueued
> Reference<? extends Foo> referenceFromQueue;
> for ( PhantomReference<Foo> reference : list) {
>     System.out.println(reference.isEnqueued());
> }
>
> // now we can call bar to do what ever it is we need done
> while ( (referenceFromQueue = queue.poll()) != null) {
>     ((FinalizeStuff)referenceFromQueue).bar();
>     referenceFromQueue.clear();
> }
> ```

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question; how is this useful in practice? System.out.println() is not useful, and since you can't get the original object reference, what could you potentially do that is useful?